# How to resend args to an app if its already running and have it refresh with those args

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, command-line-interface

I have an issue. I'd have a video player that takes in simple parameters as a c# form app. As an experiment to better understand programming, I'd like to have only one instance of the app running and have it refresh with the new args if the open command is given. I could program it so that when it gets the signal, to refreshVideo() or something like that.

Pseudo example:

```
//app is started from cmd line

//open app for first time
vidViewer.exe("lotr.avi", "44:44");

//keep instance open but have it refresh with new movie
vidViewer.exe("star_wars.avi", "22:32")
```

As it stands right now a new app with embedded video player will open, so I could have 100 open flicks if I passed it enough args. I'd just like to keep it at one.

Can provide more info if needed.

Thanks all,
Kevin

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to design your application such that, when launched, it would attempt to acquire a system resource that is mutually exclusive (meaning that only the first instance would succeed). Since, in your scenario, you will also require a means of interprocess communication (to transmit the name and start-time of new videos), you may use the same mechanism for achieving this.

You could, for example, use a self-hosted WCF service, bound to a fixed TCP port, that each application instance attempts to register upon being started. Due to the way ports work, only the first instance will succeed; subsequent instances would fail with a “port already in use” exception.

- If an instance manages to register the WCF service, then you may assume it to be the “principal” instance and proceed to play the video on it. It should, however, listen for incoming messages from the WCF service and update the video being played accordingly (see below).
- If an instance finds that the port is already in use, it should assume that another instance is already running. It would then initialize a WCF client that sends the name and start-time of the new video to be played to the WCF service. Finally, it should terminate itself without displaying any window, assuming that the principal instance will take care of playing its video.

Comment: Ok, so I have step one working with the example here [codeproject mutex](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/62684/Allow-only-one-instance-of-a-c-application). Now to implement the WCF.

Comment: I’ve made some updates to my post (you may eliminate the need for a `Mutex` if you use a self-hosted WCF service bound to a fixed port); see whether it’s clearer now.

Comment: Douglas, I appreciate the feedback. I am also looking into memory mapped files and window messages. (keeping options open and learning)

Comment: Fair enough. WCF has a steep learning curve, so if you’re not already familiar with it, you would probably be better off going for something simpler. Even a plain old `TcpListener` would do the trick.